# Limiting or eliminating parallel processing in GSTools v1.5.1

Tags: python, kriging

I am running a series of processes using GSTools v1.5.1 on a large machine where I want to only use one thread. It seems that vario_estimate uses all available processes, increasing processing time from ~0.005 seconds to 20-30 seconds. How can this multithreaded behavior be turned off? I have tried setting os.environ['RAYON_NUM_THREADS'] = '1', per the very limited [documentation](https://geostat-framework.readthedocs.io/projects/gstools/en/stable/) , in several places but this does not seem to have the desired effect.